# How to publish PowerShell scripts to an internal fileshare from VisualStudio.com

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

As part of our suite of Microsoft products, we have been "given" a visualstudio.com  account to use to store our PowerShell Scripts/Modules in, and to use for version control.

One thing we don't seem to be able to figure out how to do, is to automate publishing the scripts in VisualStudio.com to our internal fileshares where the scripts are run from.

For example, I update BuildAutomation.ps1, and an automated process/PowerShell script/elf then copies the published script to \BuildServer\Share1$.

I feel like we can't be the first SysAdmin team that would like to do this, but I haven't been able to find anything to describe if such a thing is even possible.
This isn't helped by potentially not even really knowing if I am using the correct terminology in my searching...

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is a way. 
It is possible to create a Build/Release pipeline where the files are copied to a local server using Windows File Copy. Yay.

You'll need to have an Agent running on  aserver that can access VSTS, and this agent then, effectively, does the copying...